# Broadcast Receiver inside a service in android

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a receiver inside a service and the receiver isnt working. I did not declare it inside the manifest as it is made it in the service. Here is the code

```
package com.todaysfuture.dynpin;


public class MyBroadcastReceiver  extends Service {



@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

     AlarmManager alarmMgr;
     PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1, hour, minute);
      Context context=getApplicationContext();
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent1, 0);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60, alarmIntent);


    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();


     final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            {

                MainActivity ii=new MainActivity();
                ii.displayer();
                String LOG_TAG="DevicePolicyAdmin";
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Service Started");
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int  minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1, hour, minute);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
                String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);
                MainActivity.minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str, 0);
            }

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    return null;
}
}
```

The Service has been declared in the manifest. Yet it isnt working. What could possibly be the issue?

EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------------

Here is the updated Service

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver  extends Service {



@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1, hour, minute);
    MainActivity ii=new MainActivity();
    ii.displayer();
    String LOG_TAG="DevicePolicyAdmin";
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Service Started");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);
    MainActivity.minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str, 0);

    return null;
}
}
```

It still isnt working

Comment: who sends broadcasts? (and how)?

Comment: There is an alarm in the same class. I need a receiver for that

Comment: Is your service remote? Have you used `android:process=":remote"` in manifest?

Comment: No its not neeraj. i havent used remote

Comment: you dont need receiver at all: use `PendingIntent.getService`

Comment: i have used that already havent i?

Comment: you cannot use `getBroadcast` when your `intent1` variable points to a `Service` (`MyBroadcastReceiver` is a `Service`), just use `getService` instead

Comment: i made an edit. check it out @pskink

Comment: what is this code inside `onBind` for? do you know when `onBind` is called?

Comment: Is it the method which runs when the service is running?

Comment: have you read `Service` documentation?